# How to publish product on google cloud marketplace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, marketplace

is there anybody know how to publish product on google cloud marketplace?
I need some doc about this ,tks

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing

Comment: @DimaGimburg actually you linked to the wrong marketplace docs. Cloud Marketplace and G Suite Marketplace are different things.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be a partner to be able to add solutions.

Send an email here for more info: cloud-partners@google.com